# Preloading data in tensorflow, bad performance

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, profiling

I followed the [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded.py) with having the whole dataset preloaded

```
with tf.variable_scope("input"):
    X_train_tf = tf.constant(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)
    data_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([X_train_tf], capacity=4096, shuffle=True)
    data_batch = tf.train.batch(data_queue, batch_size=batch_size, capacity=4096)
...
create_model(data_batch)
...
sess.run(training_step)
```

where X_train is a numpy ndarray of shape (3100, 10, 9, 9) and where I then use data_batch as I previously used a tf.placeholder in the graph.

This works, but it's actually slower than when I was just using feed_dict. I'm getting around 40% GPU usage so I'm guessing this part is the bottleneck.

The input producer and batch queue implicitly adds a summary op each which tells me that the batch queue is never full. The summary op "input/batch/fraction_of_4096_full" from tf.train.batch constantly reports 0.0 actually but I'm not sure why.

I'm using tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession which should handle starting the queue runners and initializing all variables.

TLDR: Why is tf.constant + tf.train.slice_input_producer + tf.train.batch resulting in a mostly empty queue of batches?